# unable to delete file from amazon s3 using ruby script

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rubygems

I am using [aws-sdk-ruby](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby) for deleting a file saved in a bucket in my amazon s3 account, but i can't figure out why i am able to delete the desired file from S3 bucket using the following code.

this is my code

```
require 'aws-sdk-v1'
require 'aws-sdk'

ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = "XXXXXXX"
ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] = '/ZZZZZZZZ'
ENV['AWS_REGION'] = 'us-east-1'


s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new
bucket = s3.bucket('some-bucket')
obj = bucket.object('https://s3.amazonaws.com/some-bucket/38ac8226-fa72-4aee-8c3d-a34a1db77b91/some_image.jpg')
obj.delete
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html) tells that it should look like this:

```
s3 = Aws::S3.new
bucket = s3.buckets['some-bucket']
object = bucket.objects['38ac8226-fa72-4aee-8c3d-a34a1db77b91/some_image.jpg']
object.delete
```

Please note:

- the square brackets,
- that the object's key doesn't include the domain and
- instead of creating an instance of `Aws::S3::Resource` create an instance of `AWS::S3`

Comment: although your answer has a bug but it solved my issue.The link you specified here helped me to realize my mistake.

Comment: @SachinSingh: Can you please explain the bug in my code? It would help readers in the future, when I correct the issue.

Comment: i have corrected it `s3.bucket['some-bucket']` to `s3.buckets['some-bucket']`, means there is no such method named `bucket` it is `buckets`.

Comment: Please note, the s3.buckets['name'].object('key').delete interface is from v1 of aws-sdk. V2 uses s3.bucket('name').object('key').delete.

Answer (score 1):

If you use  API version 3 (aws-sdk-s3 (1.81.1)) you should do something like below:

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new
s3.delete_object(bucket: 'bucket_name', key: 'bucket_folder/file.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
objs = bucket.objects('https://s3.amazonaws.com/some-bucket/38ac8226-fa72-4aee-8c3d-a34a1db77b91/some_image.jpg')
objs.each {|obj| obj.delete}
```

Comment: you solution will delete all files from bucket.

Comment: but aren't you providing a specific file as key? Alternative can be to provide the bucket(which has the file) name as key(which you pointed out in your comment above) and then: `file_to_del = objs.detect { |obj| obj.name == "YOUR FILE NAME"}; file_to_del.delete`

Comment: I have deleted object from s3, but sorry not actually for this question.

Answer (score 0):

With the aws-sdk v2: I had to do this: (see [Doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/Resources/Batch.html))

```
$s3.bucket("my-bucket").objects(prefix: 'my_folder/').batch_delete!
```

(`delete` is deprecated in favor of `batch_delete`)

Useful post: https://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx1H87IVGVUMIB5/Using-Resources