# Rails aws-sdk cannot delete file on Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

My code does not delete the file in my Amazon S3 bucket and I don't know why.

**Logs**

```
Processing by PicturethingsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {
    "authenticity_token"=>"eEmuCyMmV8K3X5xp4rCozbwv8EnU6bZY3+juwBr/v8ScPCP/nbQ5+pgXWZOJkuJ3ZNrfDaNTx86ailFKjwTLCw==", 
    "picid"=>"10", 
    "picture_url"=>"//websmash.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/faa8c7d2-0261-4753-9cbb-c4ea06520721/picture1.png"}
```

**Picturethings controller**

```
before_action :delete_picture_from_s3, only: [:destroy]
before_action :set_s3_direct_post,  only: [:edit]

def destroy
  @picturething = Picturething.find(params[:picid])
  @picturething.destroy # this works fine
  redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
end

def delete_picture_from_s3
  S3_BUCKET.object(params[:picture_url]).delete
  return true
  rescue => e
    # Do nothing. Leave the now defunct file sitting in the bucket.
    return true
end

private

  def set_s3_direct_post
    @s3_direct_post = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/${filename}", success_action_status: '201', acl: 'public-read')
  end
```

**picturething.rb**

```
class Picturething < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates  :picture, presence: true
  .
  .
end
```

**In the view**

```
<%= button_to delete_picture_path(
                params: {
                  picid:       standardpicture.id,
                  picture_url: standardpicture.picture
                }
              ),
              class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs',
              data: { confirm: "Delete picture: are you sure?" },
              method: :delete do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<% end %>
```

**initializer**

```
Aws.config.update({
  region: 'us-east-1',
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']),
})
S3_BUCKET = Aws::S3::Resource.new.bucket(ENV['S3_BUCKET'])
```

The rails bit works fine - the picture is deleted from the rails database no problem. But the picture remains in the amazon bucket.

Comment: Did you check [unable to delete file from amazon s3 using ruby script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421972/unable-to-delete-file-from-amazon-s3-using-ruby-script)?

Comment: Yes, that's an aws-sdk version 1 solution. I'm using version 2. As far as I can tell, according to the [version 2 docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/index.html) my code should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working. I was submitting the url rather than the key. The key is obtained from the url by slicing off the host bit:

**Picturethings controller**

```
def delete_picture_from_s3
  key = params[:picture_url].split('amazonaws.com/')[1]
  S3_BUCKET.object(key).delete
  return true
  rescue => e
    # Do nothing. Leave the now defunct file sitting in the bucket.
    return true
end
```

Comment: Thank you!! Nothing else I found explained this correctly.

Comment: I'm passing the key but it still doesn't work
The thing is, AWS returns 204 response, but I can still access the object via URL