# How to delete an image from AWS S3 bucket in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Need help!

I want to delete an image from AWS S3 bucket using this code below..

```rb
Aws.config.update(
credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id), Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key)),
region: Rails.application.credentials[:aws][:region]
)

s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new.bucket(Rails.application.credentials[:aws][:bucket])
obj = s3.object('public/job/1611056483791.jpeg')
obj.delete
```

I am getting this error below.. pls help

#### Error

```
<struct Aws::S3::Types::DeleteObjectOutput delete_marker=nil, version_id=nil, request_charged=nil>
```

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27482698/14843902) useful for you?

Comment: hello, @amitd thanks for reply.. this solution is not working! I am getting the same error